# Welcome image not loading..Discord Bot In Python

Tags: python, discord

This code is giving a new member a role,but does not send the Welcome image and text.

```
@client.event
async def     on_member_join(member):
   role =     discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Crew')
   await member.add_roles(role)
   channel = member.guild.system_channel
   backround = Editor("pic1.png")
   profile_image = await load_image_async(str(member.avatar.url))
   profile = Editor(profile_image).resize((150,150)).circle_image()
   poppins = Font.poppins(size=50, variant="bold")
   poppins_small = Font.poppins(size=20, variant="light")
   backround.paste(profile, (325,90))
   backround.ellipse((325,90),150, 150, outline="white",stroke_width=5)
   backround.text((400, 260), f"WElCOME TO {member.guild.name}", color = "white", font=poppins, align="center")
   backround.text((400,325), f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}", color= "white", font=poppins_small, align="center")
   file = File(fp=backround.image_bytes, filename='pic1.png')
   await channel.send(f"Hello {member.mention}! Welcome to {member.guild.name}")
   await channel.send(file=file)
```